# ngbTooltip Resizing Depending on the Content

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

So I have created a tooltip in my angular app using ng-bootstrap v4.2.1.(working with an old codebase)
And for the content of the tooltip, I have some very long sentences.
I want this tooltip to take 800px width. But when I specify the width, I only see the first few words that fill the 800px.
Here's the code

HTML:

```
<button type="button" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip=" {{Description}}" tooltipClass ="description" style="padding: 0; font-size: 1.2em; margin: 0; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
            <i class="fal fa-info-circle" style="color: #757575;" ></i>
        </button>
```

TS:

```
let Description:string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut dignissim orci, eu feugiat nisi. Aliquam consequat condimentum tortor, ut ullamcorper lacus vestibulum eu. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id purus in massa imperdiet egestas. Ut purus purus, venenatis a egestas quis, fermentum quis dolor. Duis porttitor, ipsum et molestie fringilla, neque enim bibendum ante, nec tincidunt augue urna vitae risus.
```

CSS:

```
.description .tooltip-inner {
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 800px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

I tried several white-space and word-wrap values but I still can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tooltip's width to automatically adjust based on the content, you don't need to specify a fixed width in the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip=" {{ Description }}" tooltipClass="description" style="padding: 0; font-size: 1.2em; margin: 0; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
  <i class="fal fa-info-circle" style="color: #757575;"></i>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.description .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

In this CSS using **max-width: none;**, you're allowing the tooltip to expand its width based on the content. The **white-space: normal;** property ensures that the text within the tooltip wraps and takes up the necessary width to display all the content

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I'm not clear. But what I want is to have a fixed width and a dynamic height